# Manual legend labels for line graph ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This seems like a fairly basic question, but I'm relatively new to ggplot2 and I can't seem to figure this out. If there is something basic about the "grammar" that I'm misunderstanding here, it would be great if someone could point me in the right direct. Or just telling me how to change these labels would be great...

Say I have this (fake) data:

```
avgTerms <- data.frame(itNum = seq(1,15),
                   i15 = runif(15,5,7),
                   i20 = runif(15,5.5,7.5),
                   i25 = runif(15,4,7),
                   i30 = runif(15,6,8))
```

I make a basic line plot with it like so:

```
#colour palette (colorblind-friendly)
cbb <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
#plot
avgTermsplot <- ggplot(data=avgTerms, aes(itNum, avgTerms[,2]))
avgTermsplot <- avgTermsplot + geom_line(aes(itNum, avgTerms[,2], colour=cbb[2]))
avgTermsplot <- avgTermsplot + geom_line(aes(itNum, avgTerms[,3], colour=cbb[3]))
avgTermsplot <- avgTermsplot + geom_line(aes(itNum, avgTerms[,4], colour=cbb[4]))
avgTermsplot <- avgTermsplot + geom_line(aes(itNum, avgTerms[,5], colour=cbb[5]))
avgTermsplot <- avgTermsplot + labs(x="Iteration Number", y="Avg # of Tags Applied")

print(avgTermsplot)
```

As you can see, the labels in the legend are the color codes. Not useful. I want them to be the column names from the data.frame. (As in, they should be `i15`, `i20`, etc.) I've tried a bunch of things, trying to assign them from the vector `names(avgTerms)[2:5]` but none of those things seem to work, so I won't list them all here. Is there a simple way to assign legend labels from a character vector?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to use data in long format for `ggplot2`, so melt your data first:

```
library(reshape2)
avgTerms.m <- melt(avgTerms, id.vars = "itNum")
```

And then assign the colours based on `variable`:

```
ggplot(data = avgTerms.m, aes(itNum, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Iteration Number", y = "Avg # of Tags Applied") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cbb)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. That's the exact result I wanted. For future reference though, is there a way to manually set the labels in the legend?

Comment: Yes, have a look at `?scale_colour_manual`, you can add labels like so:   `scale_colour_manual(values = cbb, labels = c("label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"))`